# Chrome extension v3 - Sending http requests and scrape a website

Tags: google-chrome-extension, httprequest, browser-extension

With manifest v2 version one could make a simple content script with GET requests to another website. XMLHttpRequest would return the webpage when setting

`xhr.responseType = 'document'`

And one could then easily call something like

`this.responseXML.getElementsByClassName('Some class name')`

to scrape the returned webpage.

With manifest v3 I'm getting the following CORS error (here I just want to make a GET request to a StackOverflow question, while the user has to have a tab opened for quora.com):

`Access to fetch at 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72333126/chrome-extension-v3-sending-http-requests-and-scrape-a-website' from origin 'https://www.quora.com/' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

I need to get the response text, so doing the suggested in the error message is not an option.

A possible workaround would be to have a background script make the http request, however the background script does not have access to the DOM capabilities of the content script. Specifically, a background script can't scrape the data as far as I'm aware.

An even more complicated solution would be to make the http request on the background, and then passing the response to the content script with a message. The problem is just, that the response object is not json but text. And I don't know of a good way to encode the whole response text into json.

This is a very simple functionality of a browser extension. I'm sure there is somehow a way to make this work.

Comment: Make the request in the background script, send the text response back to the content script, parse it using DOMParser there.

Answer (score 0):

Content Scripts Interact With The DOM

Manifest:

```
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["scripts/content.js"],
      "matches": [
        "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/*",
        "https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the Official Example From Google V3 Docs

https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/getstarted/tut-reading-time/